# Simplifying Tightly Packing Multiple Images

Tags: software-rec, web-development, css

I’m trying to place several images in a blog entry and am finding it a challenge to determine the correct order and CSS alignments to pack them tightly so that there is minimal space. I tried simply dragging the images around in WordPress in visual-mode, but that caused a loss of data (the anchor tags were removed), plus, I still have to manually change the alignments.

Is there a program that can make this process easier?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can read about various algorithms and grab the code on the following link. The context is for packing images together in CSS sprites but the methods should apply equally well to regular images.

[Fast Optimizing Rectangle Packing Algorithm for Building CSS Sprites](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu)

Comment: I’ve already seen a dozen pages about that (including the one you linked to). I’m not in the mood to write code for what I would use once in a blue moon. I’m just looking for a program or website that facilitates this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

[ZeroSprites](http://zerosprites.com/) is a CSS sprites generator aimed at area minimization using algorithms used in the field of VLSI floorplanning. It can generate tighter sprites sheet than [Sprite Generator](http://spritegenerator.codeplex.com/) and [Spritemapper](http://yostudios.github.com/Spritemapper/).